# Not able build apache mod_tile in openSuse error: Could not find apxs on the path

Tags: apache2, openstreetmap, tiles, opensuse

I want to run a tiles server with OSM data

i want to install mod_tile so i followed the [mod_tile setup](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mod_tile#Install_mod_tile_From_Source)

But when i do the

./configure

It says

```
checking for getloadavg... yes
checking for apxs... no
checking for apxs2... no
checking for /opt/local/apache2/bin/apxs... no
configure: error: Could not find apxs on the path.
```

any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [the Internets](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=opensuse%20apache2%20apxs) you need to install `apache2-dev` (previously known as `apache2-devel`). The `apx` binary should then be located under */usr/bin/apxs2* or */usr/sbin/apxs2*.

Note: For building a tile server you should follow the [guide on switch2osm](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/).

Comment: I had to install apache2-dev on Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu

> sudo apt-get install apache2-devel

For RedHat & CentOs

> yum install httpd-devel

Comment: Isn't this question for openSuse?

Answer (score 0):

SUSE has removed the SDK ISO from the area where you download the server ISO.
[Check out this page](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=%2Fusr%2Fsbin%2Fapxs).

I consider their page as very complicated and not logical so play a bit around but you find it in the end.

When you are looking for a current version then it helps you check `Last 6 months`

Comment: Thx, I changed it to the rpm download page with lot of selections...