# mod_tile rendere is not working with apache on openSUSE

Tags: apache, openstreetmap, mapnik

i want to run tile server

i configured by following this [Link](http://wiki.planimate.com/Tile_Server_(2012)#Install_Mapnik_library)

When i try to access the http://myserver.domain/osm_tiles/0/0/0.png i'm getting the response as

**Object not found!**

When i see the apache log it says socket file is missing

```
tile_state: determined state of default 0 0 0 on store 7f05ba987d70: Tile size: -1, expired: 1 created: 0
[Thu Nov 06 16:15:59.396965 2014] [tile:debug] [pid 6334] ./src/mod_tile.c(166): [client 192.168.1.180:52068] Connecting to renderd on Unix socket /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
[Thu Nov 06 16:15:59.397003 2014] [tile:warn] [pid 6334] [client 192.168.1.180:52068] socket connect failed for: /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock with reason: No such file or directory
[Thu Nov 06 16:15:59.397007 2014] [tile:notice] [pid 6334] [client 192.168.1.180:52068] Failed to connect to renderer
[Thu Nov 06 16:15:59.397010 2014] [tile:debug] [pid 6334] ./src/mod_tile.c(960): [client 192.168.1.180:52068] tile_storage_hook: Missing tile was not rendered in time. Returning File Not Found
```

What went wrong in the configuration..

Comment: `/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock` doesn't exist. Is `renderd` running?

Comment: Not able to find that.. I think problem in installing  mod_tile

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able build apache mod\_tile in openSuse error: Could not find apxs on the path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758904/not-able-build-apache-mod-tile-in-opensuse-error-could-not-find-apxs-on-the-pat)

Comment: @scai you are right i have to start that renderd but the issue is its not able to build.. we can close this with your comment as answer.. thanks